# Which is the correct way of pasting?

Tags: excel

I want to ask a very simple and maybe for some it may sound silly. 
One person told that while copying and pasting in Excel you should use Paste Special and **paste formats first and then values**, then it keeps any leading zeros or else they will be removed. But someone else told other way round i.e. **first values and then formats**. I didn't notice any change also if I pasted as it is after copying.

So please tell me if these people are true and if yes which exactly is the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the joy of Excel conversions. You have to be cautious with your different circumstances.

Time to have some fun. Try this:
In cell A1 format the data as Text and enter the value 010. 
In cell A2 leave the format as general and enter as 010.

Now go to the immediate window in VBIDE and execute the following:

```
? Typename(Range("A1").Value)
? Typename(Range("A2").Value)
```

A1 is a string, and A2 is a double.
If you change the format of A1 now to General then again type:

```
? Typename(Range("A1").Value)
```

It is still string - AND it still has the leading 0 at the front!

HOWEVER: now execute the following:

```
range("A1").Value = range("A1").Value
```

Although this looks like a pointless command - its effectively updates the cell by using VBA. Excel will now do the conversion to a double!!

```
? Typename(Range("A1").Value)
```

This is now a double.

So altering the format after the data can result in different data because Excel is doing a clever conversion. But this is dependant on the cell being updated. Just changing the cell format might change that value, but not necessarily - and later it could change if a user presses F2 and enter on the cell.  Lovely - thank you excel for being intelligent.

Don't even get me started with other conversions.

So, I suggest that in the majority of cases, you should actually format first and data after.

Happy pasting! :)

Answer (score 0):

Cell value and cell format are two distinct properties of a cell in Excel.

For displaying values, excel applies the format of the cell to its value. So if your cell holds a number and the format specifies that the number should have leading zeros, the number will be displayed with a leading zero. *This does not change the underlying value!*

The format affects only the display.

As an example:
Let's say your cell holds the value `5.5` as numerical value. Applying the format `0.00` will display that value as `5.50`. Applying the format `0.00 min` will display the same value as `5.50 min`. But the value itself is still unchanged `5.5` - this way, you can e.g. be very specific about how you want to display a number, but still use its plain value for calculations. Same principles apply to every other formatting rule and data type of course.

So no matter which way round you paste - as long as the cells end up with the correct combination of value and format, you will end up with the correct result.

Comment: I agree with PaulG as I am asking when I do the copy and paste from web or other sources. @sina - you can see this if you copy and paste 010 on this page as it is excel will display as 10 only and when you format as text then only it is displayed as 010. Anyway Thanks for your responses and clearing my doubt.

Comment: Thats obviously another usecase. If you paste a number in Excel, it will be stored as numerical value, therefore omitting the leading 0.